# warning Bison compilation

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

am developping a compiler using flex/bison.
I have this warning in my build output.

`warning:  type clash ('s' '') on default action`

any help please?

Comment: It's not a 'compilator', it's a 'compiler'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be related to your %token and %type declaration in your source.
without the source line and the related token and type declaration it is difficult to help you.

If you specify an expr of type val and definer an ID token of type tptr

```
%{
#include "parser.h"
%}
%type <val> expr
%token <tptr> ID
```

If you write without any action bison will emit a warning

```
expr : ID;

warning: type clash ('tptr' 'val') on default action
```

Note that the bison level I am currently using print a slighty different message in this case.

```
foo.by:10.12:warning: type clash on default action : <tptr> != <val>
```

To fix this warning you need an explicit action:

```
expr : ID { $$ = some_conversion_code($1); }
```

http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/bison.html#Token-Decl

Comment: @VGCE so what would the op do to correct the warning? What should go in the action?

Answer (score 0):

Use the union definition to type your given tokens from lex.